# dynamically create uiimageview when BOOL var is true

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I asked earlier on how to display uiimageview when bool var is true. Now I need to create uiimageview dynamically. How will I able to create an uiimageview consecutively if the app detects that bool var is true?
Sample:

```
BOOL var1= true;
BOOL var2 = false;
BOOL var3 = true;

if(var1)
    {
        cell.incentive1.hidden = false;
    }
    if(var2)
    {
        cell.incentive2.hidden = false;
    }
    if(var3)
    {
        cell.incentive3.hidden = false;
    }
```

How will i make uiimageview for var3 to be displayed beside var1's uiimageview?

Answer (score 2):

set a your booleans as properties

```
@property (strong, atomic) BOOL var3;
```

Implement the setters in order to create the image view when is true

```
- (void) setVar3:(BOOL)var3
{
    _var3 = var3;
    if (_var3){
        [self createUIImageView];
    }
}
```

I assume that you already got how to implement createUIImageView